# UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText returns [Function]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm using this code here, for one of my google sheets:

```
const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText;
const data = Utilities.parseCsv(content);
```

However if I use console.log, it tells me that;
content returns: `[Function]`
and
data returns: `[ [ 'function () { [native code] }' ] ]`

I already validated that the URL is working, if I paste the URL in the browser directly.

I want to know if I'm missing something here?

The url is correct, since if I'm opening it, it downloads the csv file.

I also looked what response code I'm getting, but it always returned a 200.

The code worked before, however now it doesn't anymore. I also asked the guys responsible for the csv if they changed anything on their end, but that's not the case.

Comment: Please modify `const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText;` to `const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText();` and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

As Tanaike said, `UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText` *is* a function. You should *call* the function to get its result. To call the function, add the missing parentheses, like this:

```
  const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText();
  const data = Utilities.parseCsv(content);
```